# How many gas centrifuges are needed to build two small nuke within a year?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

imagine this is 1960-70.....a country has nuclear plants already (for peaceful purposes) now if they get the technology of gas centrifuges what things they are going to need for building two small nukes within a year? and if they want to detonate this like a time bomb, is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [On the theoretical aspects of the development of the first nuclear bombs](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73398/)

Comment: you aren't by any chance the leader of a small country with nuclear power plant technology who just acquired a gas centrifuge? Are you?

Comment: ohh yeah......i am basar al asad.....using a fake account to get the information about making nukes....from strangers in the internet :D

Comment: trying to write book bro :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the first part of your question, I think gas centrifuge specifications and capabilities may be classified which would make a reasonably exact estimate quite hard. The [Fat Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Man) nuclear bomb (20kt-yield, implosion design) required 6.2kg of plutonium (or, if the country is unwilling to take the extra step of converting its uranium to plutonium in nuclear reactors, about 13kg of highly enriched uranium would give off a similar yield).

Nuclear bombs can be designed to detonate based on any number of conditions (specific atmospheric pressure, sudden acceleration, manual command, etc.) and using a timer to trigger the bomb would be very simple.

The timer would send an electric signal to the control circuits for the bomb, which would then trigger fast, synchronized pulses to special detonators (often [exploding-bridgewire detonators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploding-bridgewire_detonator)). The detonators would initiate a layer of conventional high explosives, which would send a shockwave to compress a core of uranium or plutonium until it reaches the critical density necessary to sustain a chain fission reaction, at which point it explodes violently, releasing a lot more energy (several orders of magnitude) than given off by the initial (conventional HE) explosion.

Comment: thnx for ur help.....can u give me a estimation (dont have to be accurate....i knw its not possible to give accurate numbers) of how many centrifuges maybe needed to get 13kg U within a year?

Comment: @user44218 if he has helped you for your novel you should give him a +1 . Here is a link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotope_separation . and another link http://www.princeton.edu/~rskemp/Kemp%20-%20Gas%20Centrifuge%20and%20Nonproliferation%20-%20SPLG.pdf . It seems that time can be shortened with this cascade method.This second link shows it is not easily done within a year or two because Iran would have done it.

Comment: i tried to give him a +1 but it says i need 15 points :( and thnx to you 2.. can u tell me how the inspection of IAEC works? assuming they are gonna need around 1500 centrifuges(not sure the number is even close or not) to make 2 bombs how they can deceive IAEC?

Comment: i meant IAEA***